# recipient_bcc_maps only those sent to particular domain

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

Just wondering if someone could confirm my understanding of recipient_bcc_maps - apologies long, busy nights.

Requirement:

We have emails being relayed through Postfix from / to various domains. For one of the domains, I wish to have any email sent to it BCC'ed to an address - eg anything sent to *@foobar.com is BCC'ed to monitor@address.com.

Solution:

I believe I can add

```
recipient_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_map
```

to my main.cf and within recipient_bcc_map have a regex but I am not sure of the code, I think it should be;

```
/^(.*@\.foobar\.com)/ monitor@address.com
```

Is this correct? And my understanding is that I dont need to  postmaprecipient_bcc_map?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this I found the answer was:

Set the line in main.cf to:

```
recipient_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_map
```

then set the recipient_bcc_map contents as:

```
/^([^@]+)\@foobar\.com$/ monitor@address.com
```